# how to verify file download completely in selenium Java if that file will go on increasing every day

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, download, automation

I can see option on internet to check the file name and verify whether the file is downloaded and the another option is checking the file size to make sure it download completely but is there any other way we can verify the file download completely if that file is increasing daily. The file i am downloading is more than 500 MB  and will go on increasing day by day so how can i code in selenium java so it will check the file and make sure it 100% downloaded.

My requirement of automation is to run the automation script and download the file everyday.

Can anyone guide me on it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a piece of code I was using to download files. Just change `filePathFull` and increase timeout in `waitSec(driver, int)`.

```
    public WebDriverWait waitSec(WebDriver driver, int sec) {return new WebDriverWait(driver, sec);}

    String filePathFull = stahovani + "exportFeedbacks_" + urlCast1.split("/")[9] + ".csv";

    waitSec(driver, 30).until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            if(Files.exists(Paths.get(filePathFull))) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            } 
        return false;
        }
    });

    File exportFile = new File(filePathFull);
        if (Files.size(Paths.get(filePathFull)) == 0) {
            try {
                waitSec(driver, 120).until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
                    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        try {
                            if(Files.size(Paths.get(filePathFull)) > 0) {
                                return true;
                                }
                            else {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                    } 
                                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        catch (IOException e) {                         
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            } 
            catch (TimeoutException e) {
        }
    }
```

There is always a .part file and until download is complete orginial file (csv in my example) has zero size.

Comment: Thank you for response with code. 
Please correct me if i am wrong as i am a beginner in automation - In my understanding it will check the file exist and check if the file size is bigger than 0. Am i correct? 
i am trying to download 500 mb zip file which will be increasing daily and then i am converting that file to CSV file and renaming it in date format. I have code for converting to CSV and renaming but just wondering if code start converting file while downloading won't it break the flow as our condition will pass after size is bigger than 0.

Comment: Yes, it check if file exists (with zero size) and then it checks for size bigger then zero. It won't break because until download is 100% complete, file.zip has zero size and there is temp file file.zip.part. Try it and if it help you please mark my answer as helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Can this be use for CSV file download also as i have to download CSV file also. Do you think below code can handle this scenario. 



 File file1 = new File("file path.csv");
                     while (!file1.exists()) {

Comment: File extension is part of String filePathFull. You can use it for any file extension you want.